# Why does XP installation takes more time than Windows 7 and 8

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp, windows-8

Installation of XP takes more time than Windows 7 and 8..Why it takes so long time? and Why Windows 7 installs faster?

Comment: What media are you using to install? what are the specs of your computer? what environment are you working in? please give more details

Comment: Because Windows 7 and Windows 8 have been improved upon.  This is the reason OS X 10.10 is faster then OS X 10.9 which is faster then OS X 10.8

Comment: Have you benchmarked all three installations on the same hardware? If so, please provide exact timing results + hardware specs. Talking about hardware specs, I would be interested to see: 1) installation media (USB/CD/DVD) + read speed 2)HDD - RPM + read/write speed 3)install types (clean/upgrade)

Comment: why is my answer downvoted?

Comment: Great answer by Mokubai below, however would still be cool to see update from OP with actual numbers and specs. This question could definitely benefit from editing. And I hope that OP is not one of those who just posts the question and disappears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the methods of install have changed.

Windows 7 and 8 installs a coherent and "common" base system and *then* configures that system by setting up the parts that are machine dependant.  This includes a default set of services and other interlinked components and a minimal registry with all the common base dlls and required items already registered.  This is fast because it is essentially a single long `copy` process followed by a short setup period.

The Windows XP installer on the other hand seems to assume nothing about the base system and instead goes through rounds of discovering devices, installing drivers, then individually registering services for startup and fully registering dlls in the way that Windows expects.  This results in several rounds of `copy` and `setup` for each component and then at the end a cleanup will happen.

What this meant was at the time XP could be tailored to suit embedded or custom systems much better, as parts of the system could simply be left out of the installer without breaking things.

Windows 7 and 8, as the base system is more interlinked and more difficult to untie, has a much larger "embedded" base.

Comment: Was XP installs (from disk) sector-based, or file-based? Win Vista onwards using WIM is all file based... I wonder if that is also an aspect to take into consideration?